# how can increase ceph osd size, created on os disk

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, ceph

I m new in ceph world, and test ceph cluster on one virtual server.

I`m creating osd , according this:
https://docs.ceph.com/docs/dumpling/start/quick-ceph-deploy/#add-ceph-osd-daemons

i create some directory:

```
mkdir /tmp/osd0
```

Run prepare & activate :

```
ceph-deploy osd prepare {osd-node-name}:/tmp/osd0

ceph-deploy osd activate {osd-node-name}:/tmp/osd0
```

and see that osd have available size only 10 Gb

How can i increase this size ?

And another question:

on my server i have 2 disk on raid md0, and  over raid create LVM:

```
pvs
  PV         VG  Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/md1   vg0 lvm2 a--  <1.82t    0
vgs
  VG  #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
  vg0   1   2   0 wz--n- <1.82t    0
lvs
  LV     VG  Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root   vg0 -wi-ao----  1.81t
  swap_1 vg0 -wi-ao---- <4.77g
```

```
 lsblk
NAME             MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                8:0    0  1.8T  0 disk
├─sda1             8:1    0    1M  0 part
├─sda2             8:2    0  977M  0 part
│ └─md0            9:0    0  976M  0 raid1 /boot
└─sda3             8:3    0  1.8T  0 part
  └─md1            9:1    0  1.8T  0 raid1
    ├─vg0-swap_1 253:0    0  4.8G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    └─vg0-root   253:1    0  1.8T  0 lvm   /
sdb                8:16   0  1.8T  0 disk
├─sdb1             8:17   0    1M  0 part
├─sdb2             8:18   0  977M  0 part
│ └─md0            9:0    0  976M  0 raid1 /boot
└─sdb3             8:19   0  1.8T  0 part
  └─md1            9:1    0  1.8T  0 raid1
    ├─vg0-swap_1 253:0    0  4.8G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    └─vg0-root   253:1    0  1.8T  0 lvm   /
```

may be best way is - create some new partition with lvm and use this for osd , but i dont know how do it ? Especialy on this disk install root partition.

Comment: Without reading the whole question I recommend to use a [new release](https://ceph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (Nautilus or Octopus), the docs you're following are very old (Dumpling).

Comment: Hm, I just install it from apt install ceph-deploy

Comment: Use dedicated (virtual) disks for ceph OSDs, it's the easiest way instead of creating subdirectories within your filesystem. With a later release you can create OSDs with `ceph-volume lvm create ...` command where you can use already prepared partitions or LVMs (again, the best way are dedicated disks). Which ceph version do you get from your repos? ceph-deploy is also kind of deprecated and unmaintained, its successor is `cephadm` since Octopus release (that's the latest).

Comment: but i have only one pv ( physical volume) on my virtual server. Its not my local virtual machine, so i cant change it without reinstall full server.
So that i create osd on folder :(

Comment: Then stick to LVMs if that makes it easier for you. You can provide the size you want the LVs to have (`lvcreate -L -n <LV_NAME> <SIZE> <VG_NAME>`). But as already mentioned, you might want to upgrade to a newer release where you can use LVM for ceph.